# Define compiler and linker in CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I would like to use CMAKE to compile a special piece of code in C99 with language extensions. Therefore I have to use a "custom" compiler and linker `/your/path/to/compiler` and `/your/path/to/linker`. How can I define the compiler and the linker command used by CMAKE?

**EDIT:**
I tried to define the compiler and linker as suggested by Equod:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /your/path/to/compiler)
set(CMAKE_CUSTOM_LINKER /your/path/to/linker)
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "<CMAKE_CUSTOM_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

But CMAKE is still not taking it:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27040.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27040.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Programms/VisualStudio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Programms/VisualStudio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/your/path/to/source/build
```

What I forgot to mention before, I am working on a Windows machine and the executable of th compiler and linker is in the PATH.

**EDIT:**
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MyProject
    VERSION 1.0
    DESCRIPTION "This is MyProject"
    LANGUAGES C
)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER my_compiler)
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE my_linker)

configure_file(include/myproject_config.h.in include/myproject_config.h)

set(HEADER_FILES include/main.h include/somefunc.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.c src/somefunc.c)

add_executable(MyProject ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(MyProject PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" )
target_include_directories(MyProject PUBLIC "../include" )
```

P.S.: `my_compiler` and `my_linker` are in PATH of `cmd` and PowerShell.

**EDIT:**
I installed MinGW now. I have *make* in my PATH as well. I updated the CMakeLists.txt file above. The *make* command tries to compile the code now with:

```
my_compiler @CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/includes_C.rsp -o CMakeFiles\MyProject.dir\src\main.c.obj -c "C:\mypath\main.c"
```

But this is not working because I need a command like:

```
my_compiler -I="../include" "C:\mypath\main.c"
```

What CMake commands do I need to configure such a behavior?

Comment: Did you put the lines before `project()`?

Comment: I added the current version of the CMakeLists.txt to the question.

Comment: Exactly - move the lines before `project()` call.. The variable `CMAKE_CUSTOM_LINKER` has no meaning, use `CMAKE_LINKER`. There are endless explanations how to pass custom compiler with cmake on the net. Also you have to reconfigure cmake with new compiler.

Comment: Is it a C project?

Comment: It is C with a language extension. This is why I cannot use a standart C compiler but the custom one I want to define...

Comment: You can't use a custom compiler this way with Visual Studio 15 2017.  You would have to develop a toolset compatible with Visual Studio and then choose the proper toolset.  Refer to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html.

Comment: Would it be possible and maybe easier to use another generator?

Comment: I updated the question to fit to my current problem of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

CMake as default C compiler uses CC environment variables. You can also specify a different compiler and linker setting CMake variables:

Compiler:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /your/path/to/compiler)
```

Linker:

```
set(CMAKE_CUSTOM_LINKER /your/path/to/linker)
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "<CMAKE_CUSTOM_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

To better understand why linker settings are done in two steps I'd suggest taking a look at how those variables are managed internally by CMake:
[CMake on github](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it still doesn't work. I have edited my question for further description.